# Creating a Survey System using Angular JS Router App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking for a solution to create a survey system in angular js using router app. I thought in to use a .js file to store the questions, example:

```
var question = [[
"What's your programming language of choose ?",
"Java",
"C/C++",
"Python",
"PHP",
"Lisp",
[
"Another question",
"option",
"option",
"option"
]];
```

Now in app angular js:

```
  .state('question1', {
      url: '/question1;',
      templateUrl: 'questions/question1.php',
      controller: function($scope) {

          $scope.title= question[0][0],
          $scope.question = [question[0][1],question[0][2][0][3];

      }


  })
```

Here, I want to make a loop to find all questions in question array. 
What would be to best way to make that ?

Comment: Uh.  Why all the nested arrays?  Why not an array of objects?  If those objects need internal array, that's fine.  But why nested arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like this

```
var question = [
{
    "question":"What's your programming language of choose ?",
    "answers":{     
        "answer_1":"Java",
        "answer_2":"C/C++",
        "answer_3":"Python",
        "answer_4":"PHP",
        "answer_5":"Lisp",
    }                   
},{

    "question":"Another question",
    "answers":{     
        "answer_1":"option",
        "answer_2":"option",
        "answer_3":"option",
        "answer_4":"option",
        "answer_5":"option",
    }           
}];

$scope.question = question;
```

and example in your html

```
<div ng-repeat="ques in question">
{{ques.question}}
<div ng-repeat="answ in ques.answers">
    <label>{{answ}}:<input type="checkbox"/></label>
</div>
```